# os and os version detection in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

how i can detect that my visitor using which os and os version in javascrtip . for example windows vista or seven or Xp and linux too .

Answer (score 14):

To detect the operating system on the client machine, your script should analyze the navigator.appVersion string. Below is a simple example of a script that sets the variable OSName  to reflect the actual client OS.

```
// This script sets OSName variable as follows:
// "Windows"    for all versions of Windows
// "MacOS"      for all versions of Macintosh OS
// "Linux"      for all versions of Linux
// "UNIX"       for all other UNIX flavors 
// "Unknown OS" indicates failure to detect the OS

var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

On your system, this script yields the following result:
Your OS: Windows

(To get more detailed OS information, your script should perform a more sophisticated analysis of the `navigator.appVersion` string, but the idea would be the same.)

Answer (score 1):

navigator.platform will give you the current platform they're using, just as navigator.userAgent will give you the whole browser string.

Comment: Only worked on FIrefox, not chrome

Answer (score 0):

Output of `navigator.appVersion` on Firefox/WinXP.

```
5.0 (Windows; en-US)
```

Output of `navigator.userAgent` on Firefox/WinXP.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
```

Output of `navigator.platform`

```
Win32
```

Comment: please Take for example . understand of it is important for me