# How to find the operating system details using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operating-system, user-agent

How can I find the OS name and OS version using JavaScript?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

If you list all of `window.navigator`'s properties using

```js
console.log(navigator);
```

You'll see something like this

```
# platform = Win32
# appCodeName = Mozilla
# appName = Netscape
# appVersion = 5.0 (Windows; en-US)
# language = en-US
# mimeTypes = [object MimeTypeArray]
# oscpu = Windows NT 5.1
# vendor = Firefox
# vendorSub = 1.0.7
# product = Gecko
# productSub = 20050915
# plugins = [object PluginArray]
# securityPolicy =
# userAgent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7
# cookieEnabled = true
# javaEnabled = function javaEnabled() { [native code] }
# taintEnabled = function taintEnabled() { [native code] }
# preference = function preference() { [native code] }
```

Note that `oscpu` attribute gives you the Windows version. Also, you should know that:

```
'Windows 3.11' => 'Win16',
'Windows 95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)',
'Windows 98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
'Windows 2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
'Windows XP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
'Windows Server 2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
'Windows Vista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)',
'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 6.1)',
'Windows 8' => '(Windows NT 6.2)|(WOW64)',
'Windows 10' => '(Windows 10.0)|(Windows NT 10.0)',
'Windows NT 4.0' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
'Windows ME' => 'Windows ME',
'Open BSD' => 'OpenBSD',
'Sun OS' => 'SunOS',
'Linux' => '(Linux)|(X11)',
'Mac OS' => '(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)',
'QNX' => 'QNX',
'BeOS' => 'BeOS',
'OS/2' => 'OS/2',
'Search Bot'=>'(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp)|(MSNBot)|(Ask Jeeves/Teoma)|(ia_archiver)'
```

Comment: Of course (Windows NT 6.2)
See this link https://bitbucket.org/cat_in_136/configuration-mania/src/07c8e0e933a50b250791e3a542bdb0021d273be5/chrome/content/confmania/useragent.xml

Comment: oscpu worked inconsistently for me when I tested it across the 4 major browsers on Windows 7. @Ludwig's solution worked consistently.

Comment: according to wikpedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_6.1 windows NT 6.1 can be either win 7, win 2008 server or windows small business server, is there a way determine which one is which?

Comment: window.navigator.oscpu is undefined in chrome

Comment: I'm also observing window.navigator.oscpu undefined in Chrome, so this solution isn't much help.

Comment: window.navigator.platform has got the OS in Chrome.

Comment: I want to get only few details form this list. could i split this details as chunk?

Comment: Does anyone know the value for Windows 10 S (the secure version)?

Comment: This fails to get the MacOS Version

Answer (score 263):

I started to write a Script to read OS and browser version that can be tested on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/). Feel free to use and extend.

**Breaking Change!**
Since September 2020 the new Edge gets detected. So 'Microsoft Edge' is the new version based on Chromium and the old Edge is now detected as 'Microsoft Legacy Edge'!

**Windows 11 detection**
Due to the problem that `navigator.userAgent` shows Windows 10 even on Windows 11 I use the [Navigator API's `navigator.userAgentData`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_useragentdata) to detect the correct version of Windows. And because this can be fetched by an asynchronous call only, we'll have to use a timeout to display the correct Windows version. Currently it is only supported by Edge, Chrome and Opera, so not 100% reliable. And I removed the flash detection.
Therefore I created a [new Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/7pL1uavk/)

Here the 'classic' detection that is not capable of detecting Windows 11.

```
/**
 * JavaScript Client Detection
 * (C) viazenetti GmbH (Christian Ludwig)
 */
(function (window) {
    {
        var unknown = '-';

        // screen
        var screenSize = '';
        if (screen.width) {
            width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
            height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
            screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
        }

        // browser
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        var version = '' + parseFloat(nVer);
        var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

        // Yandex Browser
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('YaBrowser')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Yandex';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 10);
        }
        // Samsung Browser
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('SamsungBrowser')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Samsung';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 15);
        }
        // UC Browser
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('UCBrowser')) != -1) {
            browser = 'UC Browser';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 10);
        }
        // Opera Next
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 4);
        }
        // Opera
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // Legacy Edge
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Edge')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Legacy Edge';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        } 
        // Edge (Chromium)
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Edg')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Edge';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 4);
        }
        // MSIE
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        }
        // Chrome
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Chrome';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        }
        // Safari
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Safari';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // Firefox
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Firefox';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
        // MSIE 11+
        else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
        }
        // Other browsers
        else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
            browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
            if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
                browser = navigator.appName;
            }
        }
        // trim the version string
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
            version = '' + parseFloat(nVer);
            majorVersion = parseInt(nVer, 10);
        }

        // mobile version
        var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

        // cookie
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = 'testcookie';
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
        }

        // system
        var os = unknown;
        var clientStrings = [
            {s:'Windows 10', r:/(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/},
            {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},
            {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},
            {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},
            {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},
            {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},
            {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},
            {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},
            {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},
            {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},
            {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},
            {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},
            {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},
            {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},
            {s:'Android', r:/Android/},
            {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},
            {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},
            {s:'Chrome OS', r:/CrOS/},
            {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11(?!.*CrOS))/},
            {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},
            {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},
            {s:'Mac OS', r:/(Mac OS|MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},
            {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},
            {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},
            {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},
            {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},
            {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}
        ];
        for (var id in clientStrings) {
            var cs = clientStrings[id];
            if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
                os = cs.s;
                break;
            }
        }

        var osVersion = unknown;

        if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
            osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
            os = 'Windows';
        }

        switch (os) {
            case 'Mac OS':
            case 'Mac OS X':
            case 'Android':
                osVersion = /(?:Android|Mac OS|Mac OS X|MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh) ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'iOS':
                osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
                osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
                break;
        }
        
        // flash (you'll need to include swfobject)
        /* script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" */
        var flashVersion = 'no check';
        if (typeof swfobject != 'undefined') {
            var fv = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion();
            if (fv.major > 0) {
                flashVersion = fv.major + '.' + fv.minor + ' r' + fv.release;
            }
            else  {
                flashVersion = unknown;
            }
        }
    }

    window.jscd = {
        screen: screenSize,
        browser: browser,
        browserVersion: version,
        browserMajorVersion: majorVersion,
        mobile: mobile,
        os: os,
        osVersion: osVersion,
        cookies: cookieEnabled,
        flashVersion: flashVersion
    };
}(this));

alert(
    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n' +
    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserMajorVersion +
      ' (' + jscd.browserVersion + ')\n' + 
    'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +
    'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +
    'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +
    'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen + '\n\n' +
    'Full User Agent: ' + navigator.userAgent
);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Well written, easy to understand and it collects all the valuable information anyone would need. Thank you for taking the time to post this!

Comment: Brilliant! The only flaw I found is that IE 11 no longer identifies itself as MS IE. I tried to post the fix is a comment here, but it was too long and wouldn't allow it. So I'll post is another response.  But otherwise, this was perfect… Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added the IE11 check in my code on http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/

Comment: Nice solution, but unfortunately doesn't work correctly for Opera Next (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser#Version_15). It is detected as Chrome. In order to check for it, get index of 'OPR' in user agent.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 is detected as Vista (because it has "Windows NT 6.0"). Full string (for IE7): "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)".

Comment: @akapelko Unfortunately Microsoft uses the same version numbers for multiple OS (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Eadel is right...        if ( (verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1 || (verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 4);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }

Comment: I was inspired by @Ludwig's code and created an open-sourced project on GitHub. https://github.com/keithws/browser-report

Comment: Added a detection for 'Edge'

Comment: navigator.appName = 'Netscape' on Chrome 64

Comment: @Ludwig May I suggest adding support for Chrome OS? `{s:'Chrome OS', r:/CrOS/}` - it'll need to go before `{s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/}`, as the Chrome OS user agent strings may also begin with `X11`... or add a little bit of a more robust check for Linux to ignore `X11` strings that include `CrOS` - `{s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11(?!.*CrOS))/}`

Comment: @skwidbreth Thanks. Added Crome OS and included the hardened Linux detection (in case someone changes the order)

Comment: Regarding to number `10` in this line `osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];`: [next macOS release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) is `11`. So the code should be updated.

Comment: @ShimonS. Thanks for the note. I've changed the general Mac OS detection. But due of lacking an OS X or OS 11 system, I would be happy if someone could be so kind and test the changes I've made in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/). In addition I added the detection of the new Edge browser (see breaking changes above).

Answer (score 113):

```
var OSName = "Unknown";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1) OSName="Windows 10";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.3") != -1) OSName="Windows 8.1";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2") != -1) OSName="Windows 8";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1") != -1) OSName="Windows 7";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") != -1) OSName="Windows Vista";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1") != -1) OSName="Windows XP";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.0") != -1) OSName="Windows 2000";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")            != -1) OSName="Mac/iOS";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("X11")            != -1) OSName="UNIX";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux")          != -1) OSName="Linux";
```

Comment: shouldn't you use `else if` from the second check?

Comment: @transang These aren't one `if` statement, they are multiple one-liner `if` statements. It checks every single one, from top to bottom.

Comment: @DanGayle that is equivalent to reverse the line order + `else if`. Personally, I would prefer a chained ternary operator, though

Answer (score 22):

JavaScript have access to the `window.navigator.platform` - a string representing the platform of the browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform

Use it to extract whatever details you need (and can). Note that there are no guarantees that the client actually uses that platform since this can easily be modified in many ways.

Try it:

```js
console.log(window.navigator.platform);
```

Comment: "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."

Comment: @ConAntonakos can you provide a reference for that statement? That isn't mentioned in the MDN link in this answer.

Comment: @Splaktar - That's so odd. That messaged was definitely there, but I see it's not anymore. I think at some point in 2016 it was considered? I also see this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506517/deprecated-javascript-os-detection-techniques), so someone else noticed it as well. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I think the docs are messed up, it still says it's deprecated in the portuguese version: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the portuguese docs and I verified that the english docs were indeed corrected at some point.

Comment: @gark do you work for Mozilla or something or did you hack it? If you hacked it how for you do it?

Comment: As of Fall 2021 it is supported in multiple browsers and is listed in a piece of code within getHighEntropyValues provided by Microsoft as the (only) official method to detect windows 11 in Chrome based browsers such as their own MS Edge. See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11 -- So while it is not used in Firefox, it is not deprecated in all browsers.

Comment: The code snipped (for completeness) from the MS Documentation from that above link: navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["platformVersion"])
 .then(ua => {
   if (navigator.userAgentData.platform === "Windows") {
     const majorPlatformVersion = parseInt(ua.platformVersion.split('.')[0]);
     if (majorPlatformVersion >= 13) {
       console.log("Windows 11 or later");
      }
      else if (majorPlatformVersion > 0) {
        console.log("Windows 10"); }
      else { console.log("Before Windows 10"); }
   } else { console.log("Not running on Windows"); } });

Comment: If you think about it, MS won't remove it any time soon, as they want it themselves so they can tell who is using windows 11 to access their products for their sales & other demographics. So, they published it officially for use in this slightly different format: navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["platformVersion"])

Comment: @ConAntonakos seems like they switch back and forth about whether it‘s deprecated or not - but as long as there’s no better solution, it‘d be stupid to remove it - all browsers still support it at least

Answer (score 17):

@Ludwig 's solution was brilliant. A couple of fixes (which didn't have to do with operating system, and I couldn't place as a comment on his original posting because this is too long):

1. IE 11 no longer identifies itself as MS IE.
2. Chrome on IOS spoofs itself as Safari

Here they are:

```
(function (window) {
    {
    /* test cases
        alert(
            'browserInfo result: OS: ' + browserInfo.os +' '+ browserInfo.osVersion + '\n'+
                'Browser: ' + browserInfo.browser +' '+ browserInfo.browserVersion + '\n' +
                'Mobile: ' + browserInfo.mobile + '\n' +
                'Cookies: ' + browserInfo.cookies + '\n' +
                'Screen Size: ' + browserInfo.screen
        );
    */
        var unknown = 'Unknown';

        // screen
        var screenSize = '';
        if (screen.width) {
            width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
            height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
            screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
        }

        //browser
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

        // Opera
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // MSIE
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        }

        //IE 11 no longer identifies itself as MS IE, so trap it
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11
        else if ((browser == 'Netscape') && (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1)) {

            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('rv:')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 3);
            }

        }

        // Chrome
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Chrome';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        }
        // Safari
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Safari';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }

            // Chrome on iPad identifies itself as Safari. Actual results do not match what Google claims
            //  at: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent?hl=ja
            //  No mention of chrome in the user agent string. However it does mention CriOS, which presumably
            //  can be keyed on to detect it.
            if (nAgt.indexOf('CriOS') != -1) {
                //Chrome on iPad spoofing Safari...correct it.
                browser = 'Chrome';
                //Don't believe there is a way to grab the accurate version number, so leaving that for now.
            }
        }
        // Firefox
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Firefox';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
        // Other browsers
        else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
            browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
            if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
                browser = navigator.appName;
            }
        }
        // trim the version string
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
            version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
            majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        }

        // mobile version
        var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

        // cookie
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = 'testcookie';
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
        }

        // system
        var os = unknown;
        var clientStrings = [
            {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},
            {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},
            {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},
            {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},
            {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},
            {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},
            {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},
            {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},
            {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},
            {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},
            {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},
            {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},
            {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},
            {s:'Windows ME', r:/Windows ME/},
            {s:'Android', r:/Android/},
            {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},
            {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},
            {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/},
            {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},
            {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},
            {s:'Mac OS', r:/(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},
            {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},
            {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},
            {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},
            {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},
            {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}
        ];
        for (var id in clientStrings) {
            var cs = clientStrings[id];
            if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
                os = cs.s;
                break;
            }
        }

        var osVersion = unknown;

        if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
            osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
            os = 'Windows';
        }

        switch (os) {
            case 'Mac OS X':
                osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'Android':
                osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'iOS':
                osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
                osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
                break;

        }
    }

    window.browserInfo = {
        screen: screenSize,
        browser: browser,
        browserVersion: version,
        mobile: mobile,
        os: os,
        osVersion: osVersion,
        cookies: cookieEnabled
    };
}(this));
```

Comment: I've started a github repo based on this. https://github.com/thorst/Browser. Aiming to be minimal, but have enough coverage.

Comment: So now all you have to do is keep updating it for every browser on every device as they're released. I don't see "Samsung SmartTV" anywhere.

Comment: @Ian Ippolito this is very helpful many thanks. Also i would like to know how can we find the edge browser and its version.

Answer (score 12):

[platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/) seems like a good one file library to do this.

Usage example:

```
// on IE10 x86 platform preview running in IE7 compatibility mode on Windows 7 64 bit edition
platform.name; // 'IE'
platform.version; // '10.0'
platform.layout; // 'Trident'
platform.os; // 'Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 x64'
platform.description; // 'IE 10.0 x86 (platform preview; running in IE 7 mode) on Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 x64'

// or on an iPad
platform.name; // 'Safari'
platform.version; // '5.1'
platform.product; // 'iPad'
platform.manufacturer; // 'Apple'
platform.layout; // 'WebKit'
platform.os; // 'iOS 5.0'
platform.description; // 'Safari 5.1 on Apple iPad (iOS 5.0)'

// or parsing a given UA string
var info = platform.parse('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.2; en; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0 Opera 11.52');
info.name; // 'Opera'
info.version; // '11.52'
info.layout; // 'Presto'
info.os; // 'Mac OS X 10.7.2'
info.description; // 'Opera 11.52 (identifying as Firefox 4.0) on Mac OS X 10.7.2'
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use this `javascript` function to check users' OS simply

```
  function getOS() {
  var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent,
      platform = window.navigator.platform,
      macosPlatforms = ['Macintosh', 'MacIntel', 'MacPPC', 'Mac68K'],
      windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'],
      iosPlatforms = ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod'],
      os = null;

  if (macosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'Mac OS';
  } else if (iosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'iOS';
  } else if (windowsPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'Windows';
  } else if (/Android/.test(userAgent)) {
    os = 'Android';
  } else if (!os && /Linux/.test(platform)) {
    os = 'Linux';
  }

  return os;
}

alert(getOS());
```

Comment: navigator.platform is deprecated in typescript

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in previous answers, navigator.platform is deprecated. We should use navigator.userAgentData but it still lack of support (firefox, safari does not support it in 2022).

Note that the navigator.userAgentData will only work for compatible browser through https.

Here is a script that will use UserAgentData with a fall back to the old way of doing it.

```
function get_platform() {
    // 2022 way of detecting. Note : this userAgentData feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS)
    if (typeof navigator.userAgentData !== 'undefined' && navigator.userAgentData != null) {
        return navigator.userAgentData.platform;
    }
    // Deprecated but still works for most of the browser
    if (typeof navigator.platform !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof navigator.userAgent !== 'undefined' && /android/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
            // android device’s navigator.platform is often set as 'linux', so let’s use userAgent for them
            return 'android';
        }
        return navigator.platform;
    }
    return 'unknown';
}

let platform = get_platform();

// examples of use
let isOSX = /mac/.test(platform.toLowerCase()); // Mac desktop
let isIOS = ['iphone', 'ipad', 'ipod'].indexOf(platform.toLowerCase()) !== -1; // Mac iOs
let isApple = isOSX || isIOS; // Apple device (desktop or iOS)
let isWindows = /win/.test(platform.toLowerCase()); // Windows
let isAndroid = /android/.test(platform.toLowerCase()); // Android
let isLinux = /linux/.test(platform.toLowerCase()); // Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find the OS name and version in the `navigator` object, as others have answered. The standard, cross-browser place to find this information is in the `navigator.userAgent` property. However, user agent strings vary widely by OS and browser.

So, I created a script to encapsulate this logic and report on the most common OSes and browsers in a familiar way, like http://www.whatsmybrowser.org.

I open-sourced the script and uploaded it to github, https://github.com/keithws/browser-report. Pull requests are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Use [DetectOS.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detectos.js). This is a simple JS definition for popular operating systems and browsers without dependencies:

```js
class DetectOS {
    constructor() {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser())
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS())
    }

    searchString(data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let
                dataString = data[i].string,
                dataProp = data[i].prop
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                    return data[i].identity
                }
            } else if (dataProp) {
                return data[i].identity
            }
        }
    }

    searchVersion(dataString) {
        let index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString)
        if (index === -1) return
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length + 1))
    }

    dataBrowser() {
        return [
            /***************
             * Chrome
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Chrome",
                identity: "Chrome"
            },
            /***************
             * Safari
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "Apple",
                identity: "Safari",
                versionSearch: "Version"
            },
            /***************
             * For Older Opera (12.18-)
             ***************/
            {
                prop: window.opera,
                identity: "Opera",
                versionSearch: "Version"
            },
            /***************
             * Internet Explorer 10
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "MSIE",
                identity: "IE10",
                versionSearch: "MSIE"
            },
            /***************
             * Internet Explorer 11
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Trident",
                identity: "IE11",
                versionSearch: "rv"
            },
            /***************
             * Edge
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Edge",
                identity: "Edge",
                versionSearch: "Edge"
            },
            /***************
             * Firefox
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Firefox",
                identity: "Firefox"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Gecko",
                identity: "Mozilla",
                versionSearch: "rv"
            },
            /***************
             * For Older Netscapes (4-)
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Mozilla",
                identity: "Netscape",
                versionSearch: "Mozilla"
            },
            /***************
             * For Newer Netscapes (6+)
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "Netscape",
                identity: "Netscape"
            },
            /***************
             * Other Browsers
             ***************/
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: "OmniWeb",
                versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
                identity: "OmniWeb"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "iCab",
                identity: "iCab"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "KDE",
                identity: "Konqueror"
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: "Camino",
                identity: "Camino"
            }
        ]
    }

    dataOS() {
        return [
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: 'Win',
                identity: 'Windows'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: 'Mac',
                identity: 'macOS'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'iPhone',
                identity: 'iOS'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'iPad',
                identity: 'iOS'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'iPod',
                identity: 'iOS'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'Android',
                identity: 'Android'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: 'Linux',
                identity: 'Linux'
            }
        ]
    }
}

const Detect = new DetectOS()

console.log("We know your browser – it's " + Detect.browser + " " + Detect.version);
console.log("We know your OS – it's " + Detect.OS);
console.log("We know everything about you.");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating a **website** or creating a **desktop app with Electron**, you may need to get the information of the Operating System the client using. So, in this particular case you can use a global property called `window.navigator`.
If you log the property in the console with `console.log(navigator)`, you will see a whole object of sub-properties that contain the information of the browser, OS, etc.

Again, if you want to create a local **NodeJS app** it is also possible! Just call the `os` module with `const os = require("os");`. then log the constant in the console. You'll get a whole object, but if you want to see the platform name you can type in `console.log(os.platform());`, and make sure you add a pair of parenthesis after `os.platform` as `platform` here is a function!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

User-Agent strings are not reliable anymore to get the platform information **(OS, OS verions, cpu-arch etc.)** because it is possible to rewrite them and even the default set by the browser are not accurate.
try "console.log(navigator)" in the browser console and check for the User-Agent field.

To address the above problems there's a new W3 proposal (https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/) which will allow user to request specific information about the platform. As of 11/05/2021, only **chromium based** browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, Brave...) have implemented the specifications (the proposal is still unofficial).

One way to get the platform information is for server to request the specific information by adding the header like this '***Accept-CH: Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version***' to the initial response and any subsequent requests from the client would contain the platform information header. For more info see the link above.

To get the information in the **client via Javascript** the below code can be used (copy and paste it in the chrome console).

```
let platformDetails = await navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["architecture", 
"platform", "platformVersion", "model", "bitness", "uaFullVersion"]);
console.log(platformDetails);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey for a quick solution you can consider the following library : UAPARSER - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js

example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ua-parser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var parser = new UAParser();
console.log(parser.getOS()) // will log  {name: "", version:""}
```

you can also install the library via npm, and import it like this:

```
import { UAParser } from 'ua-parser-js';
let parser = new UAParser();
parser.getOS();
```

the library is a JS based user agent string parser (window.navigator.userAgent is the user agent on browser) , so you can get with it other details aswell such as Browser,device,engines etc..and it can work with node js as well.

if you need typing for the library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ua-parser-js

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorUAData/platform

```js
console.log(navigator.userAgentData.platform)
```

Examples: `macOS`, `Windows`

**Caution**: `window.navigator.platform` is deprecated

Comment: have you had a look at the compatibility list? if so, you wouldve noticed that not all browsers support this interface. Probably not what OP wanted. Simplest but not the most reliable way would be user agent.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a library for parsing User Agent strings called [Voodoo](http://github.com/saebekassebil/voodoo). But be aware that this should *not* be used instead of feature detection.

What Voodoo does, is that it parses the userAgent string, which is found in the Navigator object (window.navigator). It's not all browsers that passes a reliable userAgent string, so even though it's the normal way to do it, the userAgent can not always be trusted.

Comment: I loved the Voodoo, but I think should be a way to easily distinguish between mobile, tablet etc... please post it at gittip so I can tip you for the nice job.

Answer (score 1):

I [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/buyskih/2agbvy3f/1/) @Ludwig code and remove necessity of `swfobject`.

I just use [swfobject code](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/source/browse/tags/swfobject_2_2/src/swfobject.js#48) for detect flash version.

```
/**
 * JavaScript Client Detection
 * (C) viazenetti GmbH (Christian Ludwig)
 */
(function (window) {
    {
    var unknown = '-';

    // screen
    var screenSize = '';
    if (screen.width) {
        width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
        height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
        screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
    }

    //browser
    var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
    var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
    var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

    // Opera
    if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Opera';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
    }
    // MSIE
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
    }
    // Chrome
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Chrome';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
    }
    // Safari
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Safari';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
    }
    // Firefox
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Firefox';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
    }
    // MSIE 11+
    else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
        browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
        version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
    }
    // Other browsers
    else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
        browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
        if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
        browser = navigator.appName;
        }
    }
    // trim the version string
    if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
    if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
    if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

    majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
    if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
        version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
    }

    // mobile version
    var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

    // cookie
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {
        document.cookie = 'testcookie';
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
    }

    // system
    var os = unknown;
    var clientStrings = [
        {s:'Windows 10', r:/(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/},
        {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},
        {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},
        {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},
        {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},
        {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},
        {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},
        {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},
        {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},
        {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},
        {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},
        {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},
        {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},
        {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},
        {s:'Android', r:/Android/},
        {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},
        {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},
        {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/},
        {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},
        {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},
        {s:'Mac OS', r:/(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},
        {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},
        {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},
        {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},
        {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},
        {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}
    ];
    for (var id in clientStrings) {
        var cs = clientStrings[id];
        if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
        os = cs.s;
        break;
        }
    }

    var osVersion = unknown;

    if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
        osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
        os = 'Windows';
    }

    switch (os) {
        case 'Mac OS X':
        osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
        break;

        case 'Android':
        osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
        break;

        case 'iOS':
        osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
        osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
        break;
    }

    var flashVersion = 'no check', d, fv = [];
    if (typeof navigator.plugins !== 'undefined' && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] === "object") {
        d = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"].description;
        if (d && !(typeof navigator.mimeTypes !== 'undefined' && navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"] && !navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin)) { // navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin indicates whether plug-ins are enabled or disabled in Safari 3+
        d = d.replace(/^.*\s+(\S+\s+\S+$)/, "$1");
        fv[0] = parseInt(d.replace(/^(.*)\..*$/, "$1"), 10);
        fv[1] = parseInt(d.replace(/^.*\.(.*)\s.*$/, "$1"), 10);
        fv[2] = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(d) ? parseInt(d.replace(/^.*[a-zA-Z]+(.*)$/, "$1"), 10) : 0;
        }
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== 'undefined') {
        try {
        var a = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
        if (a) { // a will return null when ActiveX is disabled
            d = a.GetVariable("$version");
            if (d) {
            d = d.split(" ")[1].split(",");
            fv = [parseInt(d[0], 10), parseInt(d[1], 10), parseInt(d[2], 10)];
            }
        }
        }
        catch(e) {}
    }
    if (fv.length) {
        flashVersion = fv[0] + '.' + fv[1] + ' r' + fv[2];
    }    
    }

    window.jscd = {
    screen: screenSize,
    browser: browser,
    browserVersion: version,
    mobile: mobile,
    os: os,
    osVersion: osVersion,
    cookies: cookieEnabled,
    flashVersion: flashVersion
    };
}(this));

alert(
    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n'+
    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserVersion + '\n' + 
    'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +
    'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +
    'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +
    'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen + '\n\n' +
    'Full User Agent: ' + navigator.userAgent
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on @Ian Ippolito answer (because I would have if I had the rep) but according to the document his comment linked, I'm fairly certain you can find the Chrome version for IOS. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent?hl=ja lists the UA as: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1

So this should work:

```
if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('CriOS')) != -1) {
                //Chrome on iPad spoofing Safari...correct it.
                browser = 'Chrome';
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);//should get the criOS ver.
            }
```

Haven't been able to test (otherwise I would have improved his answer) it to make sure since my iPad is at home and I'm at work, but I thought I'd put it out there.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this :)

```js
getPlatform() {
    const allPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE', 'Android', 'iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod'];
    return allPlatforms.find(item => item === navigator.platform);
}
```

Comment: `navigator.platform` is deprecated.

Comment: I guess Linux has not been invented yet.