# Make Text Appear For Windows Viewers Only

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a website for batch files. Since batch files only work on Windows computers I want to find a code that recognizes the difference from Windows and other devices. Once I have this code I tell it to display a check mark and the download link on windows and on other platforms (iPhones, Android phones, ChromeBooks, etc.) It will say your device is not compatible with this file. I haven't found anything on the web even similar to this.

Comment: Check out this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Comment: On another note, it'll be better to detect this Server Side.

Answer (score 1):

This javascript checks if the user uses windows.

`if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1){document.write('using windows');};`