# Shift content to next line if horizontal scroll is present using javascript/jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section containing several div...whenever horizontal scroll is present into the section, how can i shift the hidden div to next line...

HTML

```
<section id="a">
<div class="num">
<div class="num">
<div class="num">
<div class="num">
<div class="num">
<div class="num">
</section>
```

CSS

```
.num
{
 position: relative;  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: table-cell` .. or just `float: left`.

Comment: what do you mean by next line?

Comment: i want to do it using javascript...not plain css...i want to render differently in different screen

Comment: @shaleen that happens automatically if you use css. I can't see why you want to do this using javascript?

Comment: in mac book i want scroll option and in desktop i don't want scroll..

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. what I understand is that you want to show the `div` elements in one line in Mac and more than one line in Windows, such that there will be no horizontal scroll. is it correct?

Comment: yes...u got it correct

Comment: @shaleen I think you need to find the OS version and then implement as needed. please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9514179/1577396).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need two things:

- [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
- [`word-wrap:break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Media queries because you should be testing and designing based on screen size, not necessarily individual devices like you appear to be wanting to do.

`word-wrap:break-word;` because this will prevent a horizontal scroll appearing if one of the div elements are too long - the element's content will simply jump to the next line.

You'd find a suitable screen size by which you wish to do your nextline-shifting at and apply `word-wrap:break-word;` to the `div.num` elements inside.

Then, in your media query for larger devices, you simply wouldn't include it, and your div elements will keep to one line with a horizontal scroll if necessary.