# How do adjust html output based on operating system?

Tags: javascript, html, linux

## Problem definition

I need to put text similar to the following on a web page:

If the user is operating on a **Windows** based system, I want them to see:

*Look for the file C:\Users\yourname\dir1\dir2\filename on your Windows PC*

If the user is operating on an **OS X** based system, I want them to see:

*Look for the file /Users/yourname/dir1/dir2/filename on your Macintosh PC*

If the user is operating on[**any other|Linux**] based system, I want them to see:

*Look for the file /home/yourname/dir1/dir2/filename on your Linux PC*

## Research

I have managed to create three almost identical javascripts that partially work.  One script gives me the value of the `osHomeDir`, another `osType`, and the other gives me the value of the `osSeparator`.  My problem is that I don't know how to get these values out of the java script and into my webpage consistently. What I get is that the first substitution works, but I can't repeat it - for instance, on my Mac I see:

*Look for the file /Users/yournamedir1dir2filename on your Macintosh PC* rather than the desired:
*Look for the file /Users/yourname/dir1/dir2/filename on your Macintosh PC*

Note how only the FIRST substitution of `osSeparator` worked.

## Desired outcome

I'm hoping someone can show me two things:

1. How to make the scripts more efficient - three almost identical
   scripts could surely be changed into one that returned three values
2. The ability to be able to use the result more than once (as happened
   in my example)

   ### Notes

Don't get too concerned about THIS example - I have simplified it to make it readable. I have the same problem in many places.  I know I *COULD* solve this one my returning the whole sentence in the one script, but that would miss the point entirely.

### My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p> Look for the file <a id="osHomeDirId"></a><a id="osSeparatorId"></a>yourname<a id="osSeparatorId"></a>dir1<a id="osSeparatorId"></a>dir2<a id="osSeparatorId"></a>filename on your <a id="osTypeId"></a> PC</p>

<script>
var osHomeDir = "/home";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) osHomeDir="C:&#92Users";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) osHomeDir="/Users";
document.getElementById("osHomeDirId").innerHTML=osHomeDir;
</script>

<script>
var osType = "Linux";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) osType="Windows";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) osType="Macintosh";
document.getElementById("osTypeId").innerHTML=osType;
</script>

<script>
var osSeparator = "/";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) osSeparator="&#92";
document.getElementById("osSeparatorId").innerHTML=osSeparator;
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: It's hardly a duplicate.  This looks more like a problem of the user wanting to refactor his three variations of the same script, as well as misunderstanding how `getElementById` works, and that setting `innerHTML` does not work the same way as setting the `html()` value using `jQuery` on a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Working Answer:

I changed approach to use functions instead of `getElementsByClassName`

I can now get the "desired" outcome, but I'm sure there could be some more efficiencies added to the script to save the `if...if else...if else` construction at the end.

Here's the code that works:

```
<script>
function localised() {
var printItem=arguments[0];
var osHomeDir="/home";
var osSeparator="/";
var osType="Linux";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
  osHomeDir="C:&#92Users";
  osType="Windows";
  osSeparator="&#92"
}
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {
  osHomeDir="/Users";
  osType="Macintosh";
}
if (printItem=="osHomeDir") document.write(osHomeDir);
else if (printItem=="osType") document.write(osType); 
else if (printItem=="osSeparator") document.write(osSeparator);

}
</script>

<p>Look for the file <script>localised("osHomeDir");</script><script>localised("osSeparator");</script>yourname<script>localised("osSeparator");</script>dir1<script>localised("osSeparator");</script>dir2<script>localised("osSeparator");</script>filename on your <script>localised("osType");</script> PC</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use document.getElementById() which only gets the first element with the specified id. Also you shouldn't use id's multiple times. You should make it a class instead. You need to use document.getElementsByClassName() which returns an array, then loop through all the elements of that array and set the `innerHTML` properties to osSeparator.

```
var separators=document.getElementsByClassName("osSeparatorId");
for(var i=0;i<separators.length;i++){
    separators[i].innerHTML=osSeparator;
}
```

Then you need to change the html to `<a class="osSeparatorId">`

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have modified my code (see below) but my result is even less successful than before - I don't even get one "osSeparatorId" :(

Comment: I edited my answer with a normal for loop, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

## Not an answer...yet

Clearly someone has got @Max Meijer's answer working (because it has been marked up) but when I try it, it still doesn't work.  @Max (or anyone else) I invite you to edit this answer until it does work.

Remember: Desired output (eg on OS X)=>
*Look for the file /Users/yourname/dir1/dir2/filename on your Macintosh PC*

Output using Max's code above=>
*Look for the file /Usersyournamedir1dir2filename on your Macintosh PC*

Note that in this case not even a **single** instance of `osSeparatorId` is displayed.

And I still have 3 separate scripts to do pretty much the same job.

Proof that I've implemented Max's code exactly as described:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!--Note that the following line is now using <a class="osSeparatorId"> instead of <a id="osSeparatorId"> --> 

<p> Look for the file <a id="osHomeDirId"></a><a class="osSeparatorId"></a>yourname<a class="osSeparatorId"></a>dir1<a class="osSeparatorId"></a>dir2<a class="osSeparatorId"></a>filename on your <a id="osTypeId"></a> PC</p>

<script>
var osHomeDir = "/home";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) osHomeDir="C:&#92Users";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) osHomeDir="/Users";
document.getElementById("osHomeDirId").innerHTML=osHomeDir;
</script>

<script>
var osType = "Linux";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) osType="Windows";
if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) osType="Macintosh";
document.getElementById("osTypeId").innerHTML=osType;
</script>

<!--Note that the following is cut and pasted from Max's answer-->    
<script>
var separators=document.getElementsByClassName("osSeparatorId");
for(var i=0;i<separators.length;i++){
    separators[i].innerHTML=osSeparator;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```