# Redirect browsers from iOS7 and over to another page

Tags: javascript, ios, browser

I'm looking for some javascript that will redirect users who are using iOS 7 and above to another page.

I've tried looking through this forum which shows how to do this with iPads etc but I can't find anything regarding a specific versions of iOS (regardless of the device).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: just serch on google and find here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User Agent String.Com](http://www.useragentstring.com/), it also has a JavaScript code that will parse the agent string to sections.

Comment: I understand that it should look something like this but how do you specify to redirect on iOS7 and above? `<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html");
}
-->
</script>`

Comment: user gent string specifies the operating system as well. so check it in your condition