# how to tell what operating system is being used from chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am making a chrome app and I would like to know the operating system that the app is being run on so I can display a different style for the operating system. It would be preferable if there is a chrome api I could use but I highly doubt that there is such a thing for determining the operating system. So how could I tell the operating system from a chrome app?

My app would not work with the instructions for the extension as app's have different api's and different restrictions than chrome extensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9514476/1365365

Comment: @JamieH there's a better Chrome API specific answer.

Comment: _"My app would not work with the instructions for the extension..."_ You are mistaken. Some APIs are shared between extensions and apps. This one in particular is [available for apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPlatformInfo); I wouldn't mark it as duplicate otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getPlatformInfo` in chrome's api.  Like this:

```
chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function(info) {
    // Display host OS in the console
    console.log(info.os);
});
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: @fauverism In which sense? Are you running this from a Chrome App context?