# What is the reliable way to detect OS using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navigator, key-events

The use of [navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) is not advised as per MDN. In my application I want to have a shortcut for del key.

In mac del key (is backspace) with charCode = 8.
In windows del key charCode = 46.

I want to treat both keyEvents same. I am currently using userAgent but it is unreliable as that property can be spoofed. I am wondering what is the best way to know the client OS otherwise.

More deprecated navigator properties
[navigator.appVersion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion)
[navigator.platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform)

```
/* code objective */
if ((keycode == 8 && os == 'macintosh') || keycode == 46) {
    //This is keyboard shortcut to perform delete
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you only looking for the OS name or you would like to know the platform as well?

Comment: https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/

Comment: @Moe - Just the OS name is good enough to differentiate macintosh

Comment: Note that keypress itself uses navigator.userAgent https://github.com/dmauro/Keypress/blob/development/keypress.js#L776

Comment: @AndersonGreen - navigator properties have been taken out of web standard. So I am looking for other ways.

Comment: I don't think you should be worried about userAgent spoofing. The only real concern as the author mentioned is that navigator and almost every property under it has been deprecated from Web standards thus making the use of most code written with it obsolete.

Comment: @SchahriarSaffarShargh - I understand and agree. I have added my code-objective. Cannot think of a way to achieve that!!

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question regarding detecting the delete key (maybe you should've titled it like that) As far as I know there are no new specs for detecting the OS (since the reason why they were deprecated was unreliability, I could be wrong though) but I think the best way to solve this is to see if there is a common way to detect backspace across platforms.

Comment: @SchahriarSaffarShargh - That's my dev box

Comment: Looks like virtual key code is the way to go but browser support? it's going be a long wait until then we are struck with navigator properties. https://twitter.com/Teoli2003/status/663995373766221824

Answer (score 1):

Relying on KeyboardEvent.metaKey and KeyboardEvent.Backspace solved my problem

Full Key Values - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

For more details refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Key_values

Thanks to @Teoli2003 for twitter reply - https://twitter.com/Teoli2003/status/663995373766221824