# How to detect Operating System with JavaScript (without deprecated window.navigator)

Tags: javascript, operating-system, navigator

Detecting the operating system of a visitor used to be easy with the `navigator.platform` solution. However, this solution is now deprecated, so my question, quite simply, is there another way to retrieve the OS using JavaScript?

I have looked around the web and everything seems to point towards the `navigator` object, but as you can see from the following link, this has been deprecated...

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: @Marco Did you even read my question??? I specifically point out that this question needs an updated answer as the other questions (including the one you have pointed out) are using a deprecated method...

Comment: Well, I didn't you know you already saw that question. There's no need to be rude.

Comment: Im not being rude @Marco, I am merely pointing out that if you read the question and not just the title, you wouldn't have marked it as a possible duplicate. I have now updated the title that should make it clearer

Comment: I have read your question. You only mentioned `navigator.platform`, while the answers in the other question mentioned many other properties, so I thought you hadn't seen it.

Comment: the link in your question points to `navigator.platform`... `Navigator` is NOT deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be usefull for you, a small project from github.

https://github.com/Pagawa/PgwBrowser
http://pgwjs.com/pgwbrowser/

The code to use `var pgwBrowser = $.pgwBrowser();`