# How do I know which platform it is?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, macos, windows-mobile

I have a page, where I need to detect which platform it is and if my apps are compatible for that platform, if it's compatible then I use native, else I use external third party tools.

using whichbrowser.net I am getting browser name, but how can I detect which architecture it is? is it PC or Tablet or SmartPhone how to get that value?

```
function waitForWhichBrowser(cb) {
  var callback = cb;                
  function wait() {
    if (typeof WhichBrowser == 'undefined') 
      window.setTimeout(wait, 100);
    else 
      callback();
  }             
  wait();
}
waitForWhichBrowser(function() {
  try {
    Browsers = new WhichBrowser({
      useFeatures:      true,
      detectCamouflage: true
    });

    var n  = Browsers.browser.name;
    var v  = Browsers.browser.version.major;
    var oo = Browsers.os;
    var d  = Browsers.isType('desktop'); // true

    console.log(oo);
    console.log(n);

    if(n=='Chrome') {
      useNativeBrowser();
    }
    else if(n=='Opera') {
      useNativeBrowser();
    }
    else if(n=='Firefox') {
      useNativeBrowser();
    }
    else {
      // NOW!! offer PC plugin or Tablet plugin or Smart phone plugin

      //----

      // How do i know now if its PC? IE or Safari or IE Edge

      // How do i know now if its Tablet? iPad, Android, Windows, Tizen?

      // How do i know now if its Smart phone? iOS, Android, Windows, Tizen

    }




  } catch(e) {

  }

});
```

Comment: You'd be better off using feature detection, rather than browser/platform detection.  Any method that checks your browser can be fooled by a simple setting change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ludwig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773740/ludwig) gave a very appropriate answer to this question in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706818/5252389). This is one of the best and the most appropriate methods to check if the user is on mobile or which os is he using.

Check out his [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/)

```
(function (window) {
    {
        var unknown = '-';

        // screen
        var screenSize = '';
        if (screen.width) {
            width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
            height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
            screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
        }

        // browser
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

        // Opera
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // Opera Next
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Opera';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 4);
        }
        // Edge
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Edge')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Edge';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        }
        // MSIE
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
        }
        // Chrome
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Chrome';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        }
        // Safari
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Safari';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
            if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
                version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
        }
        // Firefox
        else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
            browser = 'Firefox';
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
        // MSIE 11+
        else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
            browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
            version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
        }
        // Other browsers
        else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
            browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
            if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
                browser = navigator.appName;
            }
        }
        // trim the version string
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

        majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
        if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
            version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
            majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        }

        // mobile version
        var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

        // cookie
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == 'undefined' && !cookieEnabled) {
            document.cookie = 'testcookie';
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
        }

        // system
        var os = unknown;
        var clientStrings = [
            {s:'Windows 10', r:/(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/},
            {s:'Windows 8.1', r:/(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/},
            {s:'Windows 8', r:/(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/},
            {s:'Windows 7', r:/(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/},
            {s:'Windows Vista', r:/Windows NT 6.0/},
            {s:'Windows Server 2003', r:/Windows NT 5.2/},
            {s:'Windows XP', r:/(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/},
            {s:'Windows 2000', r:/(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/},
            {s:'Windows ME', r:/(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/},
            {s:'Windows 98', r:/(Windows 98|Win98)/},
            {s:'Windows 95', r:/(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/},
            {s:'Windows NT 4.0', r:/(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/},
            {s:'Windows CE', r:/Windows CE/},
            {s:'Windows 3.11', r:/Win16/},
            {s:'Android', r:/Android/},
            {s:'Open BSD', r:/OpenBSD/},
            {s:'Sun OS', r:/SunOS/},
            {s:'Linux', r:/(Linux|X11)/},
            {s:'iOS', r:/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/},
            {s:'Mac OS X', r:/Mac OS X/},
            {s:'Mac OS', r:/(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/},
            {s:'QNX', r:/QNX/},
            {s:'UNIX', r:/UNIX/},
            {s:'BeOS', r:/BeOS/},
            {s:'OS/2', r:/OS\/2/},
            {s:'Search Bot', r:/(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/}
        ];
        for (var id in clientStrings) {
            var cs = clientStrings[id];
            if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
                os = cs.s;
                break;
            }
        }

        var osVersion = unknown;

        if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
            osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
            os = 'Windows';
        }

        switch (os) {
            case 'Mac OS X':
                osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'Android':
                osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
                break;

            case 'iOS':
                osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
                osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
                break;
        }

        // flash (you'll need to include swfobject)
        /* script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" */
        var flashVersion = 'no check';
        if (typeof swfobject != 'undefined') {
            var fv = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion();
            if (fv.major > 0) {
                flashVersion = fv.major + '.' + fv.minor + ' r' + fv.release;
            }
            else  {
                flashVersion = unknown;
            }
        }
    }

    window.jscd = {
        screen: screenSize,
        browser: browser,
        browserVersion: version,
        browserMajorVersion: majorVersion,
        mobile: mobile,
        os: os,
        osVersion: osVersion,
        cookies: cookieEnabled,
        flashVersion: flashVersion
    };
}(this));

alert(
    'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n' +
    'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserMajorVersion +
      ' (' + jscd.browserVersion + ')\n' + 
    'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +
    'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +
    'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +
    'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen + '\n\n' +
    'Full User Agent: ' + navigator.userAgent
);
```

All credit goes to [Ludwig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773740/ludwig)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is just an Extension to [Sukrit Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356836/javascript-how-do-i-know-which-platform-it-is/40357077#40357077)'s Answer.
When you are on a **Tizen** device the var jscd.os would hold 'Linux' and jscd.mobile would hold 'true' as [Tizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizen) is an operating system based on the Linux kernel.Thus you can determine you are on Tizen platform.

```
 if ( jscd.os == "Linux" &&  jscd.mobile == true)
     // You are on Tizen Platform
```

Sharing screenshots of the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/) from different devices..

Android (Galaxy S5)

[image]

Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

Tizen (Samsung Z1)

[image]

Tizen (Samsung Z3)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Where do you get the Tizen emulator? do you also have Windows mobile emulator to test it myself?

Comment: I have tested on real devices Samsung Z1 and Samsung Z3.  Don't have a windows mobile emulator....

Answer (score 0):

To detect the operating system on the client machine, your script can analyze the value of navigator.appVersion or navigator.userAgent. Below is a simple example of a script that sets the variable OSName to reflect the actual client OS.

```
// This script sets OSName variable as follows:
// "Windows"    for all versions of Windows
// "MacOS"      for all versions of Macintosh OS
// "Linux"      for all versions of Linux
// "UNIX"       for all other UNIX flavors 
// "Unknown OS" indicates failure to detect the OS

var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

On your system, this script yields the following result: 
Your OS: Windows

Comment: On Android devices just returns Linux

Comment: because android is Linux))

Answer (score 0):

```
    I went through various posts and found this two things.
    1)by ,hecking user agent.

    /**
     * Determine the mobile operating system.
     * This function returns one of 'iOS', 'Android', 'Windows Phone', or 'unknown'.
     *
     * @returns {String}
     */
    function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
      var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

          // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
        if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
            return "Windows Phone";
        }

        if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
            return "Android";
        }

        // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
        if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
            return "iOS";
        }

        return "unknown";
    }

2. User sniffing

var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;
```