# Wrong screen resolution detected - Why is a smaller resolution detected?

Tags: javascript, css, screen-resolution

I just noticed that my screen resolution is not right detected.
If I use [THIS](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706818/5859685) I get a resolution of *1280 x 720*.
But if I look in my Windows options I have a resolution of *1920 x 1080*.

So I set my resolution (in Windows) to *800 x 600* and checked it again in the links above. Now both are showing *800 x 600* too.

My questions: 
Why is my higher resolution not detected by js/css?

I made a little "table" with the different resoutions (right windows/ left js,css):

[image]

It looks like the proportion between both values are the same for every pair.

EDIT: Thanks to Schlaus, I tried it with different queries und colors. And css is also detecting just up to 1280 x 720 and not higher.

Comment: Check that your browser's zoom level is 100%.

Comment: Also, this would be ridiculously easy to test. Just make a page with a media query, that changes the background of page to red if the width is below a threshold, and blue otherwise (pick colors to your liking).

Comment: The zoom lvl doesn't affect the displayed resolution in js. I just tried it. But the zoom is at 100%.

Comment: Is it just the 1920x1080 that displays incorrectly or if you select other resolutions above 1280 x 720 do you get similar issues?

Comment: All resolutions above are displayed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the scaling in Windows 10.
It was set to 150%.
After changing it to 100% everything was displayed correctly.

On desktop -> right click -> display settings

Comment: Is there a way to get the scaling value itself? I don't know which API (maybe Win32) I should use for this.

Comment: I havent tried it but this seem the way to go.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorfordevice