# Detect whether ios, android or desktop to launch different links?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

I m trying to make my website social icon, refer to a link (when clicked) based on the platform being used on. like the following:

- if The website is opened on ios phone, ipad... to launch a specific deep link.
- if The website is opened on android phone ... to launch a specific deep link.
- if The website is opened on desktop pc ... to launch a specific link.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP Header.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Through the User-Agent field you can get the browser version etc. Other header could be interesting for you, too.

Comment: oh, thank you for your help! but i wanted some help in writing the jquery code to perform the detection and if statements.