# How to conditionally render ReactJS content based of user's Operation System

Tags: reactjs, operating-system, conditional-rendering

I am looking for a solution to render `React` content conditionally based off the user's Operating System.

Eg. I have a simple component that displays keyboard shortcuts to interact with another component I'm using. In this case, the keyboard shortcuts for `Windows` and `Linux` are meant to show `ctrl + [action]`. But for `MacOS` it needs to show `cmd + [action]`.

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { ShortcutsContainer, MetaRow } from '../../styles';

const Shortcuts = () => (
  <ShortcutsContainer>
    <h1>Keyboard Shortcuts</h1>
    <MetaRow>
      <strong>ctrl + click</strong>
      <span> to start editing value</span>
    </MetaRow>
    <MetaRow>
      <strong>ctrl + Enter</strong>
      <span> to submit changes</span>
    </MetaRow>
    <MetaRow>
      <strong>Escape</strong>
      <span> to cancel editing</span>
    </MetaRow>
  </ShortcutsContainer>
);

export default Shortcuts;
```

Let's take `<strong>ctrl + click</strong>` from that.

What I want is to have something like this:

```
<strong>{getUserOS() === 'MacOS' ? 'cmd' : 'ctrl'} + click</strong>
```

How would I accomplish that? Been struggling to find a way to get the user's OS.

Comment: So, the real question seems to be: how do I detect user OS using Javascript? You can check some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Comment: Yeah you're right @MiguelCalderón, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so thanks to @MiguelCalderón recommending I go check the vanilla JS Solution. I check it out and got a solution that works for this use case.

I've created this simple little function:

```
const cmdOrCtrl = () => (window.navigator.platform.match(/^Mac/) ? 'cmd' : 'ctrl');
```

And then just implemented it as follows:

```
<strong>{cmdOrCtrl()} + click</strong>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.navigator.platform
```

returns for which platform the browser is compiled

Answer (score 1):

May be we can use [Platform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform) module to do that.

Just `var platform = require('platform');` it and use `platform.os` to get the OS.

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question correctly, you are interesting in knowing the operating system of user. 
You can use something like this

```
getUserOs= () =>{
 return window.navigator.platform;
}
```