# Chrome Extension to get local operating system version number/ patch number/ build number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am on a HCI program and I am now working on **Chrome extension**. I wonder if there is way Chrome extensions can fetch local **operating system**'s version number.

I am now trying to **read system's update logging** so that I might extract the version number using REGEX. Yet it now seems that there is no way I can get access to files in OS due to security concerns and Chrome permission.

Can anyone give some tips or tell us this is **completely impossible**? Thanks guys!

*************************update 4/6/2018*******************************

To be clear, my goal is to see if OS has been updated to its newest version so that I am be able to remind users of safety updates. Thus I need very detailed info such as version number(e.g. Windows 10, 1709), patch number, build number(e.g. OS Build 16299.125), etc. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There are several properties in the `navigator`. Maybe they provide you the needed information.

```js
console.log("navigator.appVersion:", navigator.appVersion);
console.log("navigator.userAgent:", navigator.userAgent);
console.log("navigator.platform:", navigator.platform);

console.log("navigator:", navigator);
```

Comment: Hi, Sebastian. I have already checked usage of  `navigator` but I need more detailed OS info. Anyway, thanks for your help!