# Display the platform of the browser in text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to find out which operation system that user used for my web?

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = "Platform: " + navigator.platform;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

but i would to save the output in text in order to save it in my database !
How can i do it??
thanks in advance

Comment: Why not do it in PHP? `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` contains that info.  You did put PHP in your tags

Comment: What do you mean by saving output as a text? Variable `x` already holds a string (text).

Comment: ^.. and if you are willing to save it in a database you need to send it to a server side language, PHP for example with AJAX or just as @Forbs mentioned use `$_SERVER` to get whatever data you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the Windows version, use the `oscpu` property of the `navigator` object instead of `platform`.

```
var osName = navigator.oscpu;
```

For more details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Hope it helps