# Get the OS-specific keyboard shortcut for copy and paste

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webapp that tells the user to copy and paste something. I want to show them the keyboard shortcut for it. How would I find out if it's
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd>, or
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd>, or even something different?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will need to handle this yourself. You can get current user system like this:

```js
var platform = window.navigator.platform;
console.log(platform);

if (platform.startsWith('Mac')) {
  console.log('use CMD + V');
} else if (platform.startsWith('Win')) {
  console.log('use CTRL + V');
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Shame, I thought there may be some nice solution. Are you sure that all apple platforms start with `Mac`?

Comment: not 100% sure, but i would bet that all intel mac computers (so all models of last decade) will have `MacIntel` as main do.

Comment: note that iOS devices have different platform, but there is no CMD key

Answer (score 0):

You could get the platform using `window.navigator.platform` and if the returned value contains 'mac' you can assume it is MacOS else if it contains 'win' it is windows.