# how to get browser and server details while execution of protractor testing

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

i have a Protractor Cucumber framework for my testing and generating the HTML reports with protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin. Here i have a metadata section where i have "Browser and Platform" related details. I need to display the execution browser details, the OS where this execution happens on these sections. How can i get the details of this during the execution.

I have tried browser capabilities, browser-detect, useragent, OS packages...but still not getting what i need. How can i get OS name, details and Browser name, version details.

Comment: `window.navigator.platform` should given you the OS name

Comment: Also refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript