# Is there a way to detect which Windows 10 version you are on using javascript?

Tags: javascript, operating-system, navigator

I am trying to determine if the user's Windows 10 version is v1511 or v1607.  I tried using navigator, but that only gives me the user agent string with just Windows NT 10.0:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36

How can I tell which Windows 10 version the user is on?

Comment: You can't.  If your user doesn't tell you in their headers, then you can't magically dig into their machine.  This is the beauty of the browser sandbox.

Comment: [Try this link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)