# How can I get OS user name with angular 6

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, active-directory

I need to get OS username, to send to a .net web api that will make an active directory checking if that user exists there and return the user info.
This is for hospital staff, that will use this app in their chrome books, so I need to check if the user who entered the operating system exists in the AD.

Comment: It's really JavaScript, nothing special, [here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript) , investigate a bit more, there are more things you can extract using window.navigator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: By the way, it's OS _name_, not _username_.

Comment: no, i want OS User name... not OS Name

Comment: how the angular app is hosted? in a node (express) environment or IIS? Are you trying to make a request to another web api rest service?

Comment: will be hosted in IIS yes, and the webapi will be too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AUTH_USER and/or LOGON_USER server variable. That should do it if it's hosted on IIS. On the backend you could do:

```
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
```

, but this may be vb.net specific.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx