# Can i load a css file only on windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load this piece of CSS only in windows.

```
/* total width */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color:#fff;
    width:6px
}

/* background of the scrollbar except button or resizer */
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#fff
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color:#f4f4f4
}

/* scrollbar itself */
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#babac0;
    border-radius:16px;
    /* border:1px solid #f4f4f4 */
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color:#a0a0a5;
    /* border:1px solid #f4f4f4 */
}

/* set button(top and bottom of the scrollbar) */
*::-webkit-scrollbar-button {display:none}
```

It is for a custom scroll bar and on mac the scroll bar is fine the way it is.

I need this to work in every browser in windows.

Is there a way to load a css file containing that piece of css code if the OS is Windows?

Comment: @Alex that seems unlikely as that addresses Internet Explorer, not windows as a whole.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Comment: @Alex They fix it with using a IE conditial comment wich won't work for me as i need it in chrome and firefox too. And only in windows

Comment: Fair play and good point, I've retracted my close flag. I can't help but think there is something else wrong if its OS specific, rather than browser.

Comment: If you haven't already, consider whether you really want a custom scrollbar as changing the appearance of native UI components can degrade user experience.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the same question has been asked before, this is what you need to do.
Use the **Navigator** object provided by javascript and check for the platform value.

Something like this:

```
function changeStyle() {
var css = document.createElement('link');
css.rel="stylesheet";
css.type = 'text/css';

if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win32")!=-1){ /* IF it is windows*/
css.href = 'stylewindows.css';
} else {
css.href = 'style.css';
}

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
return false;
}
```

Comment: or just Win64, if you don't do WOW.