# Fetch OS level information through website

Tags: javascript, python, php, browser, operating-system

I need to get certain OS-level information. I cannot install anything on client's machines, I only have option to open a URL in the browser on client's machines. I need to get following information if possible.

- get OS version
- Have they run Windows Update
- Any Pending reboots waiting (from software installs) it causes issues with SentryBay install
- Audio settings

  - The name of the default recording and playback devices
  - Whether either of those devices are muted
  - Whether either of those devices’ volume is at 0
- CPU
- RAM
- Should be running Defender only (for PCs)
- Are they using wifi
- What is running on PC (if their CPU usage is high they may need to close down or uninstall software)
- Safe Mode needs to be off

The website can be coded in any language JS, PHP, Python etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I sure **hope** that's not possible :-)

Comment: This is generally not possible, the exception being if you want to require Internet Explore.  Using IE, you could write an ActiveX plugin that could report this information.

Comment: To give up that information would be a VERY bad idea. As others have already mentioned some, very limited, information may be obtained but you aren't going to get most of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I already knew that most of the items are not possible but still i just wanted to explore more ideas. This has been very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most of this is not possible due to security concerns, however some browsers have implemented web APIs that can access some of this information. [What Web Can Do Today](https://whatwebcando.today/) has some great information about what sorts of device specific data can be accessed using APIs that were mostly designed for [Progressive Web Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application).

Update: There is information on how to access the OS version in JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can actually get the OS information of a device with PHP. It can tell if the user is using, Windows 7 or Windows 8 or Windows 10 or Android or Mac OS or IOS or more with this code:

```
<?php

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform  = "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array     = array(
                          '/windows nt 10/i'      =>  'Windows 10',
                          '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                          '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                          '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                          '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                          '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                          '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                          '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                          '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                          '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                          '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                          '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                          '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                          '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                          '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                          '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                          '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                          '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                          '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                          '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                          '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                          '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                          '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                    );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value)
        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent))
            $os_platform = $value;

    return $os_platform;
}

$user_os        = getOS();

$device_details = "<strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_os."";

print_r($device_details);

?>
```