# Is there any method to get information from operating system in browser by using js？

Tags: javascript

Is there any method to get information from operating system in browser by using js？

like python:

```
os.path.dirname
```

Comment: related topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the operating system version using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript)

Comment: use window.navigator

Comment: For certain specific things, yes, but in general, no. For instance, what do you expect the equivalent of `os.path.dirname` to do if run from JS in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

[**Navigator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) for device and os details and configuration. You could use the keys as you wish

```
navigator.platform
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, it can be accessed through the [navigator object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) but it can be very sophisticated to extract these informations, so consider using a library like [bowser.js](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser)