# How can I use systeminformation in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, sapper

So, I'm learning svelte + sapper, and I want to use systeminformation to retrieve detailed hardware, system and OS information.

I installed it with ' npm i systeminformation ' and it shows on node_modules, but I don't know how to use/require/import it.
For example, I want to see my cpu information, but I don't know how to use it on my .svelte file.

This is what I want to use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation 
https://systeminformation.io/gettingstarted.html

I'm so sorry if this is a really noob question, and thank you so much for any help in advance!!!
Also, english is not my main language, so... sorry if i could not express my doubt properly.

Thank you again!
:D

Comment: Is there a way to collect system data, like cpu, temperature, ram, wifi, and others on svelte?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check [svelte-adaptive-sensors](https://github.com/pngwn/svelte-adaptive-sensors) which export stores for system info.

From the readme :

> Sensors to help you deliver adaptive sensors to users depending on their network-type, memory, cpu, and saveData settings. A svelte version of react-adaptive-hooks although there are very few differences between the two libraries currently.

Answer (score 1):

systeminformation is purely for node and will not work in the browser, at most it might work in a server route for sapper but even then it will only give you information about the server you are running

it will not work in a `.svelte` component.

Comment: Ahh, okay!!! Thank you so much!!!! Is there a way to collect system data, like cpu, temperature, ram, wifi, and others on svelte?

Comment: there is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript but generally I don't think it's possible due to security reasons (I wouldn't personally want a random website be able to tell what temperature my computer is running)