Unity WebGL check mac or windows
In Unity, I know that you can check the operating system using  Application.platform
I'm using the WEBGL build however, so Application.platform is set to WebGLPlayer
How do I figure out whether I'm on Mac or PC in a WEBGL build?
I need it for visual changes like "press this button on your keyboard" adjusting to the mac / windows keyboard.

Youd have to pass something from the browser. As its the same build for phone, linux,mac etc

You can use a Plugin and then gather that OS information JavaScript side -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-details-using-javascript
